# How to change height of tabs Angular Material Design

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to accomplish a simple layout with Angular2 and Angular Material. This is the idea:

```
<div class="viewport-home">
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <span class="toolbar-title">{{'app.name' | translate}}</span>
    <button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-menu x-position="before" #menu="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>{{'home.menu.logout.label' | translate}}</button>
  </md-menu>
  <md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs="always" md-dynamic-height>
    <md-tab label="{{'home.tab-design.label' | translate}}">
      <design></design>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="{{'home.tab-gallery.label' | translate}}">

    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="{{'home.tab-suggestions.label' | translate}}">

    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

My only issue is that I want to set the height of the tabs to fill the height of the viewport using flex but, I do not which is the class or directive that I should modify in my CSS. When I inspect the code in Chrome's devtools, I see a lot of nested elements and I am not sure how to do it.

I'd apprecite any help. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this ?

Comment: @jmls Nope, I dropped the project. I made it with plain CSS and JS. Much better. :)